# How to add hyperlink to slide with Interop

Tags: hyperlink, interop, powerpoint

How to add hyperlink to concrete slide inside presentation using c#?
For now I have found how to Hyperlink to a site:

TextRange.ActionSettings[Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.PpMouseActivation.ppMouseClick].Hyperlink.Address = "http://www.google.com";

and found options to Last/First/Next

TextFrame.TextRange.ActionSettings[PpMouseActivation.ppMouseClick].Action = PpActionType.ppActionFirstSlide;

but not to slide4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add the setting manually in PowerPoint then ask it what the setting is, it'll tell you.  For example, add a link to Slide 4 to a text box, make sure the text box is selected and run this:

```
Sub Thing()
    Dim oSh As Shape
    Set oSh = ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange(1)
    With oSh
        Debug.Print .ActionSettings(1).Hyperlink.Address
        Debug.Print .ActionSettings(1).Hyperlink.SubAddress
    End With
End Sub
```

The result, a blank line (no hyperlink address) and a subaddress of:

```
259,4,Title of slide 4
```

259 is the SlideID
4 is the SlideIndex
"Title of slide 4" is the title text on slide 4

I'm fairly sure the ID and Index are necessary; the title is not.  For example to set a link to slide 3 in the same presentation:

```
Sub ThingTwo()
    Dim oSh As Shape
    Set oSh = ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange(1)
    With oSh
        .ActionSettings(1).Hyperlink.Address = ""
        .ActionSettings(1).Hyperlink.SubAddress = "258,3,"
    End With
End Sub
```

Doing it in c# ... left as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: Thanks!, I have debugged the powerpoint but only the Address property not the subaddress. :)